# Python dataframe returns empty spacings after replacing dots from the original context

Tags: python, regex, dataframe, for-loop

The original dataframe contains dots in the number, for instance: 3.200.000. In this case, the dot represents a thousand separator instead of a comma, and I tried to remove the thousand separator using the following code:

```
pattern_shareholding_numbers = re.compile(r'[\d.]*\d+')

shareholding_percentage_df = df[(~df["Jumlah Lembar Saham"].str.startswith("Saham") & (df["Jabatan"] == "-"))]
shareholding_percentage_df = df[(~df["Jumlah Lembar Saham"].str.startswith("Jumlah Lembar Saham") & (df["Jabatan"] == "-"))]
shareholding_percentage_df.reset_index(drop=True, inplace=True)
shareholding_percentage_list = df["Jumlah Lembar Saham"].to_list()
shareholding_percentage_string = ' '.join(shareholding_percentage_list)
matches = pattern_shareholding_numbers.findall(shareholding_percentage_string)

matches_dot_removed = []
for dot in matches:
    dot_removed = []
    for e in dot:
        e = e.replace('.', '')
        e = e.replace('.', '')
        dot_removed.append(e)
    matches_dot_removed.append(dot_removed)

shareholding_percentage_float = str(matches_dot_removed).rstrip('')
print(shareholding_percentage_float)
```

The code on the above successfully replaced the thousand separator, and it's now returning something like the following:

```
[['3', '', '2', '0', '0', '', '0', '0', '0'], ['2', '', '9', '0', '0', '', '0', '0', '0'], ['2', '', '9', '0', '0', '', '0', '0', '0'], ['1', '', '0', '0', '0', '', '0', '0', '0']]
```

I am trying to find a way to remove the spacings, and squish the numbers together so that it will be something like:

```
['3200000'], ['2900000'], ['2900000'], ['1000000']
```

Comment: Are these numbers all integers or could they have real decimal places?

Answer (score 0):

If the numbers are definitely integers then:

```
numberstring = '320.000.000'
numbers = numberstring.split('.')
dot_removed= ''.join(numbers)
print(dot_removed)
# 320000000
```

Answer (score 0):

you could iterate through the list of mixed value number strings, with the replace statement you have already. For example if you have

```py
num_list = ['3.200.000.', '2.200.000.', '2.900.000.', '4.300.000.']
```

then

```py
numeric = []
for num in num_list:
    numeric.append(num.replace('.', ''))

print(numeric)
```

will output

```
['3200000', '2200000', '2900000', '4300000']
```